# Cannot open .jtl Jmeter result after running test in terminal

Tags: jmeter

When I run a Jmeter Testplan in apache-jmeter-5.4 from the terminal and later try to import the result to the script in the GUI i get the following error (see attached image):

[Error in GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cbDTc.png)

Would appreciate input what I might do wrong in the process when it comes to importing the result.

I am running this on a Ubuntu:

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
Release:    20.04

**Command:**

```
jmeter -n -t /home/usr/jmeter/script.jmx -l /home/usr/jmeter/scriptjtl
```

**Scrip:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jmeterTestPlan version="1.2" properties="5.0" jmeter="5.4">
  <hashTree>
    <TestPlan guiclass="TestPlanGui" testclass="TestPlan" testname="Test Plan" enabled="true">
      <stringProp name="TestPlan.comments"></stringProp>
      <boolProp name="TestPlan.functional_mode">false</boolProp>
      <boolProp name="TestPlan.tearDown_on_shutdown">true</boolProp>
      <boolProp name="TestPlan.serialize_threadgroups">false</boolProp>
      <elementProp name="TestPlan.user_defined_variables" elementType="Arguments" guiclass="ArgumentsPanel" testclass="Arguments" testname="User Defined Variables" enabled="true">
        <collectionProp name="Arguments.arguments"/>
      </elementProp>
      <stringProp name="TestPlan.user_define_classpath"></stringProp>
    </TestPlan>
    <hashTree>
      <ThreadGroup guiclass="ThreadGroupGui" testclass="ThreadGroup" testname="Thread Group" enabled="true">
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.on_sample_error">continue</stringProp>
        <elementProp name="ThreadGroup.main_controller" elementType="LoopController" guiclass="LoopControlPanel" testclass="LoopController" testname="Loop Controller" enabled="true">
          <boolProp name="LoopController.continue_forever">false</boolProp>
          <stringProp name="LoopController.loops">1</stringProp>
        </elementProp>
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.num_threads">5</stringProp>
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.ramp_time">1</stringProp>
        <boolProp name="ThreadGroup.scheduler">false</boolProp>
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.duration"></stringProp>
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.delay"></stringProp>
        <boolProp name="ThreadGroup.same_user_on_next_iteration">true</boolProp>
      </ThreadGroup>
      <hashTree>
        <HTTPSamplerProxy guiclass="HttpTestSampleGui" testclass="HTTPSamplerProxy" testname="HTTP Request" enabled="true">
          <elementProp name="HTTPsampler.Arguments" elementType="Arguments" guiclass="HTTPArgumentsPanel" testclass="Arguments" testname="User Defined Variables" enabled="true">
            <collectionProp name="Arguments.arguments"/>
          </elementProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.domain">opensource-demo.orangehrmlive.com</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.port"></stringProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.protocol"></stringProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.contentEncoding"></stringProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.path">/</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.method">GET</stringProp>
          <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.follow_redirects">true</boolProp>
          <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.auto_redirects">false</boolProp>
          <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.use_keepalive">true</boolProp>
          <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.DO_MULTIPART_POST">false</boolProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.embedded_url_re"></stringProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.connect_timeout"></stringProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.response_timeout"></stringProp>
        </HTTPSamplerProxy>
        <hashTree/>
      </hashTree>
    </hashTree>
  </hashTree>
</jmeterTestPlan>
```

**Errorlog:**

```
2021-04-16 15:50:32,813 ERROR o.a.j.u.JMeterUtils: Unexpected error - see log for details
2021-04-16 15:53:26,153 WARN o.a.j.s.CSVSaveService: Unknown column name 1618580568520
2021-04-16 15:53:26,153 INFO o.a.j.s.CSVSaveService: /home/martin.jonsson/Jmeter/Result/result.jtl does not appear to have a valid header. Using default configuration.
2021-04-16 15:53:26,154 WARN o.a.j.s.CSVSaveService: Insufficient columns to parse field 'allThreads' at line 1
2021-04-16 15:53:26,154 WARN o.a.j.r.ResultCollector: Problem reading JTL file: /home/martin.jonsson/Jmeter/Result/result.jtl
org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterError: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 12 out of bounds for length 12
    at org.apache.jmeter.save.CSVSaveService.makeResultFromDelimitedString(CSVSaveService.java:381) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4]
    at org.apache.jmeter.save.CSVSaveService.processSamples(CSVSaveService.java:170) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4]
    at org.apache.jmeter.reporters.ResultCollector.loadExistingFile(ResultCollector.java:379) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4]
    at org.apache.jmeter.visualizers.gui.AbstractVisualizer.stateChanged(AbstractVisualizer.java:247) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.util.FilePanelEntry.fireFileChanged(FilePanelEntry.java:140) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.util.FilePanelEntry.actionPerformed(FilePanelEntry.java:155) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4]
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1967) [?:?]
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2308) [?:?]
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:405) [?:?]
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:262) [?:?]
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:279) [?:?]
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6635) [?:?]
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3342) [?:?]
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6400) [?:?]
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2263) [?:?]
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:5011) [?:?]
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2321) [?:?]
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4843) [?:?]
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4918) [?:?]
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4547) [?:?]
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4488) [?:?]
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2307) [?:?]
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2772) [?:?]
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4843) [?:?]
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:772) [?:?]
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721) [?:?]
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715) [?:?]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85) [?:?]
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:95) [?:?]
    at java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:745) [?:?]
    at java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:743) [?:?]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85) [?:?]
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:742) [?:?]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203) [?:?]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124) [?:?]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113) [?:?]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109) [?:?]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101) [?:?]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90) [?:?]
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 12 out of bounds for length 12
    at org.apache.jmeter.save.CSVSaveService.makeResultFromDelimitedString(CSVSaveService.java:318) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4]
    ... 40 more
```

**Updated problem description**

As @Dmitri T said there seemed to be an old version of jmeter when running the command `jmeter --version` resulted in the suggested output below:

```
Copyright (c) 1998-2015 The Apache Software Foundation
Version 2.13.20180731
```

Therefore I used the following command to remove Jmeter from Ubuntu repositories:

```
apt-get autoremove jmeter -y
```

I addition to that i updated the Java version to:

```
openjdk version "11.0.10" 2021-01-19
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.10+9-Ubuntu-0ubuntu1.20.04)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.10+9-Ubuntu-0ubuntu1.20.04, mixed mode, sharing)
```

After that I executed the following command in "bin" folder of my JMeter 5.4 installation:

```
./jmeter -n -t /home/usr/jmeter/script.jmx -l /home/usr/jmeter/scriptjtl
this ./ bit is uber important because it instructs shell to execute the JMeter startup script from the current folder.
```

**This resulted in a new output file:**

```
1618579509193,1440,HTTP Request,200,OK,Thread Group 1-1,text,true,39604,5,5,502
1618579509459,1180,HTTP Request,200,OK,Thread Group 1-3,text,true,39604,5,5,240
1618579509259,1419,HTTP Request,200,OK,Thread Group 1-2,text,true,39604,3,3,436
1618579509659,1026,HTTP Request,200,OK,Thread Group 1-4,text,true,39604,2,2,249
1618579509859,2907,HTTP Request,200,OK,Thread Group 1-5,text,true,39604,1,1,700
1618580134592,1209,HTTP Request,200,OK,Thread Group 1-3,text,true,39604,5,5,261
1618580134791,1070,HTTP Request,200,OK,Thread Group 1-4,text,true,39604,4,4,244
1618580134392,1476,HTTP Request,200,OK,Thread Group 1-2,text,true,39604,3,3,402
1618580134343,1574,HTTP Request,200,OK,Thread Group 1-1,text,true,39604,2,2,451
1618580134991,1129,HTTP Request,200,OK,Thread Group 1-5,text,true,39604,1,1,238
1618814671397,1044,HTTP Request,200,OK,Thread Group 1-2,text,true,,39604,272,5,5,https://opensource-demo.orangehrmlive.com/,218,0,104
1618814671269,1173,HTTP Request,200,OK,Thread Group 1-1,text,true,,39604,272,5,5,https://opensource-demo.orangehrmlive.com/,320,0,173
1618814671397,218,HTTP Request-0,301,Moved Permanently,Thread Group 1-2,text,true,,372,136,5,5,http://opensource-demo.orangehrmlive.com/,218,0,104
1618814671594,848,HTTP Request,200,OK,Thread Group 1-3,text,true,,39604,272,5,5,https://opensource-demo.orangehrmlive.com/,218,0,105
1618814671269,330,HTTP Request-0,301,Moved Permanently,Thread Group 1-1,text,true,,372,136,5,5,http://opensource-demo.orangehrmlive.com/,320,0,173
1618814671616,825,HTTP Request-1,200,OK,Thread Group 1-2,text,true,,39232,136,5,5,https://opensource-demo.orangehrmlive.com/,747,0,512
1618814671594,218,HTTP Request-0,301,Moved Permanently,Thread Group 1-3,text,true,,372,136,5,5,http://opensource-demo.orangehrmlive.com/,218,0,105
1618814671603,839,HTTP Request-1,200,OK,Thread Group 1-1,text,true,,39232,136,5,5,https://opensource-demo.orangehrmlive.com/,762,0,525
1618814671813,629,HTTP Request-1,200,OK,Thread Group 1-3,text,true,,39232,136,5,5,https://opensource-demo.orangehrmlive.com/,553,0,315
1618814671792,769,HTTP Request,200,OK,Thread Group 1-4,text,true,,39604,272,2,2,https://opensource-demo.orangehrmlive.com/,218,0,104
1618814671792,218,HTTP Request-0,301,Moved Permanently,Thread Group 1-4,text,true,,372,136,2,2,http://opensource-demo.orangehrmlive.com/,218,0,104
1618814672011,550,HTTP Request-1,200,OK,Thread Group 1-4,text,true,,39232,136,2,2,https://opensource-demo.orangehrmlive.com/,447,0,240
1618814671991,789,HTTP Request,200,OK,Thread Group 1-5,text,true,,39604,272,1,1,https://opensource-demo.orangehrmlive.com/,235,0,113
1618814671991,235,HTTP Request-0,301,Moved Permanently,Thread Group 1-5,text,true,,372,136,1,1,http://opensource-demo.orangehrmlive.com/,235,0,113
1618814672228,552,HTTP Request-1,200,OK,Thread Group 1-5,text,true,,39232,136,1,1,https://opensource-demo.orangehrmlive.com/,452,0,241
1618815155017,988,HTTP Request,200,OK,Thread Group 1-2,text,true,,39604,272,5,5,https://opensource-demo.orangehrmlive.com/,219,0,105
1618815155213,788,HTTP Request,200,OK,Thread Group 1-3,text,true,,39604,272,5,5,https://opensource-demo.orangehrmlive.com/,218,0,104
1618815155017,220,HTTP Request-0,301,Moved Permanently,Thread Group 1-2,text,true,,372,136,5,5,http://opensource-demo.orangehrmlive.com/,219,0,105
1618815155213,218,HTTP Request-0,301,Moved Permanently,Thread Group 1-3,text,true,,372,136,5,5,http://opensource-demo.orangehrmlive.com/,218,0,104
1618815155238,767,HTTP Request-1,200,OK,Thread Group 1-2,text,true,,39232,136,5,5,https://opensource-demo.orangehrmlive.com/,668,0,456
1618815155431,570,HTTP Request-1,200,OK,Thread Group 1-3,text,true,,39232,136,5,5,https://opensource-demo.orangehrmlive.com/,474,0,262
1618815154890,1138,HTTP Request,200,OK,Thread Group 1-1,text,true,,39604,272,3,3,https://opensource-demo.orangehrmlive.com/,303,0,166
1618815154890,308,HTTP Request-0,301,Moved Permanently,Thread Group 1-1,text,true,,372,136,3,3,http://opensource-demo.orangehrmlive.com/,303,0,166
1618815155204,824,HTTP Request-1,200,OK,Thread Group 1-1,text,true,,39232,136,3,3,https://opensource-demo.orangehrmlive.com/,714,0,490
1618815155412,784,HTTP Request,200,OK,Thread Group 1-4,text,true,,39604,272,2,2,https://opensource-demo.orangehrmlive.com/,234,0,112
1618815155412,234,HTTP Request-0,301,Moved Permanently,Thread Group 1-4,text,true,,372,136,2,2,http://opensource-demo.orangehrmlive.com/,234,0,112
1618815155648,548,HTTP Request-1,200,OK,Thread Group 1-4,text,true,,39232,136,2,2,https://opensource-demo.orangehrmlive.com/,444,0,235
1618815155614,822,HTTP Request,200,OK,Thread Group 1-5,text,true,,39604,272,1,1,https://opensource-demo.orangehrmlive.com/,235,0,113
1618815155614,235,HTTP Request-0,301,Moved Permanently,Thread Group 1-5,text,true,,372,136,1,1,http://opensource-demo.orangehrmlive.com/,235,0,113
1618815155851,585,HTTP Request-1,200,OK,Thread Group 1-5,text,true,,39232,136,1,1,https://opensource-demo.orangehrmlive.com/,475,0,251
1618815226871,953,HTTP Request,200,OK,Thread Group 1-2,text,true,,39604,272,5,5,https://opensource-demo.orangehrmlive.com/,220,0,106
1618815226871,220,HTTP Request-0,301,Moved Permanently,Thread Group 1-2,text,true,,372,136,5,5,http://opensource-demo.orangehrmlive.com/,220,0,106
1618815227092,732,HTTP Request-1,200,OK,Thread Group 1-2,text,true,,39232,136,5,5,https://opensource-demo.orangehrmlive.com/,633,0,396
1618815227066,808,HTTP Request,200,OK,Thread Group 1-3,text,true,,39604,272,4,4,https://opensource-demo.orangehrmlive.com/,234,0,112
1618815227066,234,HTTP Request-0,301,Moved Permanently,Thread Group 1-3,text,true,,372,136,4,4,http://opensource-demo.orangehrmlive.com/,234,0,112
1618815227300,574,HTTP Request-1,200,OK,Thread Group 1-3,text,true,,39232,136,4,4,https://opensource-demo.orangehrmlive.com/,474,0,239
1618815226731,1180,HTTP Request,200,OK,Thread Group 1-1,text,true,,39604,272,3,3,https://opensource-demo.orangehrmlive.com/,281,0,143
1618815226731,287,HTTP Request-0,301,Moved Permanently,Thread Group 1-1,text,true,,372,136,3,3,http://opensource-demo.orangehrmlive.com/,281,0,143
1618815227023,888,HTTP Request-1,200,OK,Thread Group 1-1,text,true,,39232,136,3,3,https://opensource-demo.orangehrmlive.com/,766,0,465
1618815227265,778,HTTP Request,200,OK,Thread Group 1-4,text,true,,39604,272,2,2,https://opensource-demo.orangehrmlive.com/,217,0,104
1618815227265,217,HTTP Request-0,301,Moved Permanently,Thread Group 1-4,text,true,,372,136,2,2,http://opensource-demo.orangehrmlive.com/,217,0,104
1618815227482,561,HTTP Request-1,200,OK,Thread Group 1-4,text,true,,39232,136,2,2,https://opensource-demo.orangehrmlive.com/,457,0,250
1618815227465,811,HTTP Request,200,OK,Thread Group 1-5,text,true,,39604,272,1,1,https://opensource-demo.orangehrmlive.com/,223,0,105
1618815227465,223,HTTP Request-0,301,Moved Permanently,Thread Group 1-5,text,true,,372,136,1,1,http://opensource-demo.orangehrmlive.com/,223,0,105
1618815227690,586,HTTP Request-1,200,OK,Thread Group 1-5,text,true,,39232,136,1,1,https://opensource-demo.orangehrmlive.com/,478,0,249
1618818979584,1037,HTTP Request,200,OK,Thread Group 1-1,text,true,,39604,272,5,5,https://opensource-demo.orangehrmlive.com/,292,0,162
1618818979584,297,HTTP Request-0,301,Moved Permanently,Thread Group 1-1,text,true,,372,136,5,5,http://opensource-demo.orangehrmlive.com/,292,0,162
1618818979887,734,HTTP Request-1,200,OK,Thread Group 1-1,text,true,,39232,136,5,5,https://opensource-demo.orangehrmlive.com/,642,0,424
1618818979718,929,HTTP Request,200,OK,Thread Group 1-2,text,true,,39604,272,4,4,https://opensource-demo.orangehrmlive.com/,222,0,105
1618818979718,222,HTTP Request-0,301,Moved Permanently,Thread Group 1-2,text,true,,372,136,4,4,http://opensource-demo.orangehrmlive.com/,222,0,105
1618818979942,705,HTTP Request-1,200,OK,Thread Group 1-2,text,true,,39232,136,4,4,https://opensource-demo.orangehrmlive.com/,598,0,369
1618818979913,774,HTTP Request,200,OK,Thread Group 1-3,text,true,,39604,272,3,3,https://opensource-demo.orangehrmlive.com/,220,0,104
1618818979913,221,HTTP Request-0,301,Moved Permanently,Thread Group 1-3,text,true,,372,136,3,3,http://opensource-demo.orangehrmlive.com/,220,0,104
1618818980135,552,HTTP Request-1,200,OK,Thread Group 1-3,text,true,,39232,136,3,3,https://opensource-demo.orangehrmlive.com/,451,0,241
1618818980112,762,HTTP Request,200,OK,Thread Group 1-4,text,true,,39604,272,2,2,https://opensource-demo.orangehrmlive.com/,218,0,105
1618818980112,218,HTTP Request-0,301,Moved Permanently,Thread Group 1-4,text,true,,372,136,2,2,http://opensource-demo.orangehrmlive.com/,218,0,105
1618818980330,544,HTTP Request-1,200,OK,Thread Group 1-4,text,true,,39232,136,2,2,https://opensource-demo.orangehrmlive.com/,442,0,231
1618818980312,833,HTTP Request,200,OK,Thread Group 1-5,text,true,,39604,272,1,1,https://opensource-demo.orangehrmlive.com/,235,0,112
1618818980312,235,HTTP Request-0,301,Moved Permanently,Thread Group 1-5,text,true,,372,136,1,1,http://opensource-demo.orangehrmlive.com/,235,0,112
1618818980549,596,HTTP Request-1,200,OK,Thread Group 1-5,text,true,,39232,136,1,1,https://opensource-demo.orangehrmlive.com/,485,0,260
```

However i seem to get a similar error in the GUI, after using the start up command for the GUI sh jmeter.sh, adding a "Listener" ([see image for set up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PFn5d.png)). Sorry for asking again but, I could not see to find anything else in link of setup that you provided (or am I missing something fundamental in the steps described above?):

```
2021-04-19 11:11:52,055 INFO o.a.j.s.FileServer: Default base='/home/martin.jonsson/apache-jmeter-5.4/bin'
2021-04-19 11:11:52,058 INFO o.a.j.g.a.Load: Loading file: /home/martin.jonsson/apache-jmeter-5.4/bin/MyPlans/commandlineexecution.jmx
2021-04-19 11:11:52,058 INFO o.a.j.s.FileServer: Set new base='/home/martin.jonsson/apache-jmeter-5.4/bin/MyPlans'
2021-04-19 11:11:52,170 INFO o.a.j.s.SaveService: Testplan (JMX) version: 2.2. Testlog (JTL) version: 2.2
2021-04-19 11:11:52,180 INFO o.a.j.s.SaveService: Using SaveService properties version 5.0
2021-04-19 11:11:52,181 INFO o.a.j.s.SaveService: Using SaveService properties file encoding UTF-8
2021-04-19 11:11:52,182 INFO o.a.j.s.SaveService: Loading file: /home/martin.jonsson/apache-jmeter-5.4/bin/MyPlans/commandlineexecution.jmx
2021-04-19 11:11:52,200 INFO o.a.j.p.h.s.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for text/html is org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.LagartoBasedHtmlParser
2021-04-19 11:11:52,200 INFO o.a.j.p.h.s.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for application/xhtml+xml is org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.LagartoBasedHtmlParser
2021-04-19 11:11:52,200 INFO o.a.j.p.h.s.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for application/xml is org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.LagartoBasedHtmlParser
2021-04-19 11:11:52,200 INFO o.a.j.p.h.s.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for text/xml is org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.LagartoBasedHtmlParser
2021-04-19 11:11:52,200 INFO o.a.j.p.h.s.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for text/vnd.wap.wml is org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.RegexpHTMLParser
2021-04-19 11:11:52,200 INFO o.a.j.p.h.s.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for text/css is org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.CssParser
2021-04-19 11:11:52,265 WARN o.a.j.g.a.Load: Unexpected error. java.lang.NullPointerException
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at java.util.ArrayDeque.addLast(ArrayDeque.java:304) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.ArrayDeque.add(ArrayDeque.java:495) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.LoadRecentProject.updateRecentFileMenuItems(LoadRecentProject.java:125) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.util.JMeterMenuBar.setProjectFileLoaded(JMeterMenuBar.java:144) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.MainFrame.setProjectFileLoaded(MainFrame.java:330) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.GuiPackage.setTestPlanFile(GuiPackage.java:732) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.Load.loadProjectFile(Load.java:136) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.Load.loadProjectFile(Load.java:101) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.Load.doActionAfterCheck(Load.java:88) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.AbstractActionWithNoRunningTest.doAction(AbstractActionWithNoRunningTest.java:44) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter.performAction(ActionRouter.java:87) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter.lambda$actionPerformed$0(ActionRouter.java:69) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4]
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:313) [?:?]
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:770) [?:?]
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721) [?:?]
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715) [?:?]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85) [?:?]
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:740) [?:?]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203) [?:?]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124) [?:?]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113) [?:?]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109) [?:?]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101) [?:?]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90) [?:?]
2021-04-19 11:11:52,271 ERROR o.a.j.u.JMeterUtils: Unexpected error - see log for details
2021-04-19 11:12:13,488 INFO o.a.j.s.SampleResult: Note: Sample TimeStamps are START times
2021-04-19 11:12:13,488 INFO o.a.j.s.SampleResult: sampleresult.default.encoding is set to ISO-8859-1
2021-04-19 11:12:13,489 INFO o.a.j.s.SampleResult: sampleresult.useNanoTime=true
2021-04-19 11:12:13,489 INFO o.a.j.s.SampleResult: sampleresult.nanoThreadSleep=5000
2021-04-19 11:12:13,574 INFO o.a.j.v.ViewResultsFullVisualizer: Add JavaFX to your Java installation if you want to use renderer: org.apache.jmeter.visualizers.RenderInBrowser
2021-04-19 11:12:18,352 WARN o.a.j.s.CSVSaveService: Unknown column name 1618579509193
2021-04-19 11:12:18,355 INFO o.a.j.s.CSVSaveService: /home/martin.jonsson/apache-jmeter-5.4/bin/MyPlans/result.jtl does not appear to have a valid header. Using default configuration.
2021-04-19 11:12:18,356 WARN o.a.j.s.CSVSaveService: Insufficient columns to parse field 'allThreads' at line 1
2021-04-19 11:12:18,356 WARN o.a.j.r.ResultCollector: Problem reading JTL file: /home/martin.jonsson/apache-jmeter-5.4/bin/MyPlans/result.jtl
org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterError: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 12 out of bounds for length 12
    at org.apache.jmeter.save.CSVSaveService.makeResultFromDelimitedString(CSVSaveService.java:381) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4]
    at org.apache.jmeter.save.CSVSaveService.processSamples(CSVSaveService.java:170) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4]
    at org.apache.jmeter.reporters.ResultCollector.loadExistingFile(ResultCollector.java:379) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4]
    at org.apache.jmeter.visualizers.gui.AbstractVisualizer.stateChanged(AbstractVisualizer.java:247) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.util.FilePanelEntry.fireFileChanged(FilePanelEntry.java:140) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.util.FilePanelEntry.actionPerformed(FilePanelEntry.java:155) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4]
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1967) [?:?]
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2308) [?:?]
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:405) [?:?]
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:262) [?:?]
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:279) [?:?]
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6635) [?:?]
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3342) [?:?]
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6400) [?:?]
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2263) [?:?]
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:5011) [?:?]
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2321) [?:?]
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4843) [?:?]
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4918) [?:?]
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4547) [?:?]
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4488) [?:?]
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2307) [?:?]
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2772) [?:?]
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4843) [?:?]
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:772) [?:?]
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721) [?:?]
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715) [?:?]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85) [?:?]
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:95) [?:?]
    at java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:745) [?:?]
    at java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:743) [?:?]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85) [?:?]
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:742) [?:?]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203) [?:?]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124) [?:?]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113) [?:?]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109) [?:?]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101) [?:?]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90) [?:?]
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 12 out of bounds for length 12
    at org.apache.jmeter.save.CSVSaveService.makeResultFromDelimitedString(CSVSaveService.java:318) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4]
    ... 40 more
```

Comment: looks like column names are not saved into the test result file. Have you done any configuration changes? Ensure jmeter.save.saveservice.print_field_names  is set to true. Also can you show first two lines of the output result file ? Thanks

Comment: @JaneshKodikara as mentioned in the updated suggestion I had an old version installed, but when I removed that version I still seem to have an error when trying to import the File to the GUI. I have updated the question with a new output i that contain any other important info that i cannot see.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using different versions for running the test and for opening the results.

If you run the command like:

```
jmeter -n -t /home/usr/jmeter/script.jmx -l /home/usr/jmeter/scriptjtl
```

it will pick up the `jmeter` binary or script **which is first on the [PATH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable))** and if you have [jmeter](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=jmeter) package installed from Ubuntu repo it explains everything

Try running `jmeter --version` command and I'm pretty much sure you will get something like:

```
Copyright (c) 1998-2015 The Apache Software Foundation
Version 2.13.20180731
```

this version is 6 years old and default [Results File Configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#results_file_config) changed several times since then

Make sure to run your test with JMeter 5.4, in order to do so:

1. Go to the "bin" folder of your JMeter 5.4 installation
2. Execute this command:

   ```
   ./jmeter -n -t /home/usr/jmeter/script.jmx -l /home/usr/jmeter/scriptjtl
   ```

   this `./` bit is uber important because it instructs shell to execute the JMeter startup script from the current folder.

More information: [Get Started With JMeter: Installation & Tests](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-get-started-jmeter-installation-test-plans)

In order to avoid future confusion I'd recommend [removing](https://www.reddit.com/r/linux4noobs/comments/60gpn9/whats_the_difference_between_aptget_autoremove_vs/) JMeter from Ubuntu repositories like `apt-get autoremove jmeter -y`.

You may need to [re-install Java](https://docs.datastax.com/en/jdk-install/doc/jdk-install/installOpenJdkDeb.html) after this: `apt-get install openjdk-8-jre -y`

Comment: Thanks for the very detailed walk-through of how to solve the problem. Unfortunately I Am still unable to read the result of the .jtl file. I have updated how I have tried to follow your instructions step-by-step.

Answer (score 0):

This is what helped me by combining the answers given here, I needed to reinstall the software doing these steps:

*** Install Jmeter

Download
apache-jmeter-5.4.1.zip from:

[Here](https://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi)

Can use this link as additional references:
[Link for installation](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-install-apache-jmeter-on-linux/)

*** Start Jmeter GUI

Open the download file from its location ex:

```
cd /home/user/Downloads/apache-jmeter-5.4.1/bin
```

Then enter to start the GUI:

```
./jmeter.sh
```

Then close the GUI

*** To start Jmeter without GUI and save as CSV navigate to:

```
cd /home/muser/Downloads/apache-jmeter-5.4.1/bin/examples
```

Execute Jmeter from commandline using this example for CSV:

```
./jmeter -n -t /home/user/Downloads/apache-jmeter-5.4.1/bin/examples/CSVSample.jmx -l /home/user/Downloads/apache-jmeter-5.4.1/bin/examples/Result/data.csv
```

Or execute Jmeter from commandline using this example for JTL

```
./jmeter -n -t /home/user/Downloads/apache-jmeter-5.4.1/bin/examples/CSVSample.jmx -l /home/user/Downloads/apache-jmeter-5.4.1/bin/examples/Result/data.jtl
```

Thereafter it is possible to open the saved data (csv/jtl) in the GUI mode